# :after pseudo-element on multi-line text

Tags: html, css, layout, pseudo-element

Is there any way to have the styling of the `:after` pseudo-element be applied on every line of some multi-line text?

The code I have is as follows:

```css
.container {
    width: 50px;
}

.text {
    position: relative;
}

.text:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6px;
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p class="text">This is some multi-line text...</p>
</div>
```

As you can see from the example, the after element is being applied correctly but only to the last line of the text, is there any way to have this styling appear on every line?

Thanks!

Comment: Are your text's lines somehow divisible in more elements (ie `span`s)? Are you trying to draw a background underneath each line of the text?

Comment: @Umbo, I am using this :after as a text underline with a gradient on it and when you hover over the text the underline turns into the entire background. There isn't really a way to divide the text into more elements.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem! The question was asked a while ago... But did you find a solution in the end?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to get a pseudo like you want.

The only way that I have found to get this kind of efect is with a background-image that covers the underlying background image. Set on this a slightly inclined transition from white to transparent. When moved from left to right, it will cover/uncover the underlying image

```css
.container {
    width: 100px;
}

.text {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, transparent 49%, white 51%);
    background-size: 5000% 1.2em;
    background-position: left center;
    transition: background-position 2s;
}

.text:hover {
    background-position: right center;

}

.text:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
    z-index: -1;
    background-size: 100% 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p class="text">This is some multi-line text...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `repeating-linear-gradient`

```css
.container {
    width: 170px;
}

.text {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.text:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, transparent 15px, red 16px, yellow 18px);
    z-index: -1;
}
.text:hover:after {
  background: none;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p class="text">This is some multi-line text...This is some multi-line text...This is some multi-line text...This is some multi-line text...This is some multi-line text...This is some multi-line text...This is some multi-line text...This is some multi-line text...This is some multi-line text...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! It doesn't seem to work in my case though. Take a look at the following pen to see the exact effect I am wanting to create. The gradient bar should be present on every line of text and, on hover, should be 100% height. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKpXJj